# How do I create strictly ordered uniformly distributed buckets out of an array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bucket-sort

I'm looking to take an array of integers and perform a partial bucket sort on that array.  Every element in the bucket before it is less than the current bucket elements.  For example, if I have 10 buckets for the values 0-100 0-9 would go in the first bucket, 10-19 for the second and so on.

For one example I can take 1 12 23 44 48 and put them into 4 buckets out of 10.  But if I have 1, 2, 7, 4, 9, 1 then all values go into a single bucket.  I'm looking a way to evenly distribute values to all the buckets while maintaining a ordering.  Elements in each bucket don't have to be sorted.  For example I'm looking similar to this.

2 1 9 2 3 8 7 4 2 8 11 4 => [[2, 1], [2, 2], [3], [4], [4], [7], [8, 8], [9], [11]]

I'm trying to use this as a quick way to partition a list in a map-reduce.

Thanks for the help.

Edit, maybe this clears things up:

I want to create a hashing function where all elements in bucket1 < bucket2 < bucket3 ..., where each bucket is unsorted.

Comment: Does it need to be more efficient than O(N.LogN)? Otherwise you can just sort the array first and then distribute it over the buckets. Also, do you know how many integers there will be in the array, and what their range of values is?

Comment: @m69, needs to be much faster.  I'm looking at 100TB of random data spreading the entire spectrum.  It's part of a map operation, but not guaranteed to be equal'ish partitioned.

Comment: I updated my answer with another example. Is any of this applicable to your problem?

Comment: Hey m69, sorry for the delay in responses.  Work got a little busy, I'll take a look at it later today.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you have around 100TB of data, or 13,743,895,347,200 unsigned 64-bit integers, that you want to distribute over a number of buckets.

A first step could be to iterate over the input, looking at e.g. the highest 24 bits of each integer, and counting them. That will give you a list of 16,777,216 ranges, each with a count of on average 819,200 so it may be possible to store them in 32-bit unsigned integers, which will take up 64 MB.

You can then use this to create a lookup table that tells you which bucket each of those 16,777,216 ranges goes into. You calculate how many integers are supposed to go into each bucket (input size divided by number of buckets) and go over the array, keeping a running total of the count, and set each range to bucket 1, until the running total is too much for bucket 1, then you set the ranges to bucket 2, and so on...

There will of course always be a range that has to be split between bucket n and bucket n+1. To keep track of this, you create a second table that stores how many integers in these split ranges are supposed to go into bucket n+1.

So you now have e.g.:

```
HIGH 24-BIT      RANGE           BUCKET    BUCKET+1

     0           0 ~    2^40-1     1          0
     1        2^40 ~  2*2^40-1     1          0
     2      2*2^40 ~  3*2^40-1     1          0
     3      3*2^40 ~  4*2^40-1     1          0
       ...
    16     16*2^40 ~ 17*2^40-1     1          0
    17     17*2^40 ~ 18*2^40-1     1    284,724  <- highest 284,724 go into bucket 2
    18     18*2^40 ~ 19*2^40-1     2          0
       ...
```

You can now iterate over the input again, and for each integer look at the highest 24 bits, and use the lookup table to see which bucket the integer is supposed to go into. If the range isn't split, you can immediately move the integer into the right bucket. For each split range, you create an ordered list or priority queue that can hold as many integers as need to go into the next bucket; you store only the highest values in this list or queue; any smaller integer goes straight to the bucket, and if an integer is added to the full list or queue, the smallest value is moved to the bucket. At the end this list or queue is added to the next bucket.

The number of ranges should be as high as possible with the available memory, because that minimises the number of integers in split ranges. With the huge input you have, you may need to save the split ranges to disk, and then afterwards look at each of them seperately, find the highest x values, and move them to the buckets accordingly.

The complexity of this is N for the first run, then you iterate over the ranges R, then N as you iterate over the input again, and then for the split ranges you'll have something like M.logM to sort and M to distribute, so a total of 2*N + R + M.LogM + M. Using a high number of ranges to keep the number of integers in split ranges low will probably be the best strategy to speed the process up.

---

Actually, the number of integers M that are in split ranges depends on the number of buckets B and ranges R, with M = N × B/R, so that e.g. with a thousand buckets and a million ranges, 0.1% of the input would be in split ranges and have to be sorted. *(These are averages, depending on the actual distribution.)* That makes the total complexity 2×N + R + (N×B/R).Log(N×B/R) + N×B/R.

Another example:

> Input: N = 13,743,895,347,200 unsigned 64-bit integers
> Ranges: 2<sup>32</sup> (using the highest 32 bits of each integer)
> Integers per range: 3200 (average)
> Count list: 2<sup>32</sup> 16-bit integers = 8 GB
> Lookup table: 2<sup>32</sup> 16-bit integers = 8 GB
> Split range table: B 16-bit integers = 2×B bytes

With 1024 buckets, that would mean that B/R = 1/2<sup>22</sup>, and there are 1023 split ranges with around 3200 integers each, or around 3,276,800 integers in total; these will then have to be sorted and distributed over the buckets.

With 1,048,576 buckets, that would mean that B/R = 1/2<sup>12</sup>, and there are 1,048,575 split ranges with around 3200 integers each, or around 3,355,443,200 integers in total. (More than 65,536 buckets would of course require a lookup table with 32-bit integers.)

*(If you find that the total of the counts per range doesn't equal the total size of the input, there has been overflow in the count list, and you should switch to a larger integer type for the counts.)*

---

Let's run through a tiny example: 50 integers in the range 1-100 have to be distributed over 5 buckets. We choose a number of ranges, say 20, and iterate over the input to count the number of integers in each range:

```
 2  9 14 17 21 30 33 36 44 50 51 57    69 75 80 81 87 94 99
 1  9 15 16 21    32 40 42 48 55 57    66 74 76    88    96
 5  6    20 24    34       50 52 58    70    78          99
    7                         51       69
                              55

 3  4  2  3  3  1  3  2  2  3  5  3  0  4  2  3  1  2  1  3
```

Then, knowing that each bucket should hold 10 integers, we iterate over the list of counts per range, and assign each range to a bucket:

```
 3  4  2  3  3  1  3  2  2  3  5  3  0  4  2  3  1  2  1  3  <- count/range

 1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  <- to bucket
          2           1        1                             <- to next
```

When a range has to be split between two buckets, we store the number of integers that should go to the next bucket in a seperate table.

We can then iterate over the input again, and move all the integers in non-split ranges into the buckets; the integers in split ranges are temporarily moved into seperate buckets:

```
bucket 1:  9 14  2  9  1 15  6  5  7
temp 1/2: 17 16 20
bucket 2: 21 33 30 32 21 24 34
temp 2/3: 36 40
bucket 3: 44 50 48 42 50
temp 3/4: 51 55 52 51 55
bucket 4: 57 75 69 66 74 57 57 70 69
bucket 5: 81 94 87 80 99 88 96 76 78 99
```

Then we look at the temp buckets one by one, find the x highest integers as indicated in the second table, move them to the next bucket, and what is left over to the previous bucket:

```
temp 1/2: 17 16 20        (to next: 2)  bucket 1: 16           bucket 2: 17 20
temp 2/3: 36 40           (to next: 1)  bucket 2: 36           bucket 3: 40
temp 3/4: 51 55 52 51 55  (to next: 1)  bucket 3: 51 51 52 55  bucket 4: 55
```

And the end result is:

```
bucket 1:  9 14  2  9  1 15  6  5  7 16
bucket 2: 21 33 30 32 21 24 34 17 20 36
bucket 3: 44 50 48 42 50 40 51 51 52 55
bucket 4: 57 75 69 66 74 57 57 70 69 55
bucket 5: 81 94 87 80 99 88 96 76 78 99
```

So, out of 50 integers, we've had to sort a group of 3, 2 and 5 integers.

---

Actually, you don't need to create a table with the number of integers in the split ranges that should go to the next bucket. You know how many integers are supposed to go into each bucket, so after the initial distribution you can look at how many integers are already in each bucket, and then add the necessary number of (lowest value) integers from the split range. In the example above, which expects 10 integers per bucket, that would be:

```
3  4  2  3  3  1  3  2  2  3  5  3  0  4  2  3  1  2  1  3  <- count/range
1  1  1  /  2  2  2  /  3  3  /  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  <- to bucket
```

```
bucket 1:  9 14  2  9  1 15  6  5  7     <- add 1
temp 1/2: 17 16 20                       <- 3-1 = 2 go to next bucket
bucket 2: 21 33 30 32 21 24 34           <- add 3-2 = 1
temp 2/3: 36 40                          <- 2-1 = 1 goes to next bucket
bucket 3: 44 50 48 42 50                 <- add 5-1 = 4
temp 3/4: 51 55 52 51 55                 <- 5-4 = 1 goes to next bucket
bucket 4: 57 75 69 66 74 57 57 70 69     <- add 1-1 = 0
bucket 5: 81 94 87 80 99 88 96 76 78 99  <- add 0
```

---

The calculation of how much of the input will be in split ranges and need to be sorted, given above as M = N × B/R, is an average for input that is roughly evenly distributed. A slight bias, with more values in a certain part of the input space will not have much effect, but it would indeed be possible to craft worst-case input to thwart the algorithm.

Let's look again at this example:

> Input: N = 13,743,895,347,200 unsigned 64-bit integers
> Ranges: 2<sup>32</sup> (using the highest 32 bits of each integer)
> Integers per range: 3200 (average)
> Buckets: 1,048,576
> Integers per bucket: 13,107,200

For a start, if there are ranges that contain more than 2<sup>32</sup> integers, you'd have to use 64-bit integers for the count table, so it would be 32GB in size, which could force you to use fewer ranges, depending on the available memory.

Also, every range that holds more integers than the target size per bucket is automatically a split range. So if the integers are distributed with a lot of local clusters, you may find that most of the input is in split ranges that need to be sorted.

If you have enough memory to run the first step using 2<sup>32</sup> ranges, then each range has 2<sup>32</sup> different values, and you could distribute the split ranges over the buckets using a counting sort (which has linear complexity).

If you don't have the memory to use 2<sup>32</sup> ranges, and you end up with problematically large split ranges, you could use the complete algorithm again on the split ranges. Let's say you used 2<sup>28</sup> ranges, expecting each range to hold around 51,200 integers, and you end up with an unexpectedly large split range with 5,120,000,000 integers that need to be distributed over 391 buckets. If you ran the algorithm again for this limited range, you'd have 2<sup>28</sup> ranges (each holding on average 19 integers with a maximum of 16 different values) for just 391 buckets, and only a tiny risk of ending up with large split ranges again.

---

Note: the ranges that have to be split over two or more buckets don't necessarily have to be sorted. You can e.g. use a recursive version of Dijkstra's Dutch national flag algorithm to partition the range into a part with the *x* smallest values, and a part with the largest values. The average complexity of partitioning would be linear (when using a random pivot), against the O(N.LogN) complexity of sorting.

Comment: Wow this is a phenomenal answer.  I was curious how you kept it strictly increasing.  it seems like you almost need to sort each bucket to find find the max per each bucket in order to bump to the next bucket.  What happens when every single element is the same value?  Will this still balance it efficiently?

Comment: @user3509528 Well, the point is that you need to use more ranges than there are buckets; if you have e.g. 100x more ranges than buckets, only 1% of the input needs sorting. But it's true that this is an average, for input that is roughly evenly distributed, and it would be possible to intentionally craft worst-case input. I'll expand the answer to address this.

Comment: Btw, how many buckets will you be using, what are the memory restrictions, and are you expecting a lot of duplicate values or any other known bias in the input?

Comment: roughly 3000 - 20,000.  Memory could be near 10TB split among all nodes / buckets.  I want roughly 64GB or less data in each bucket.  I can do both, but I wanted it to be able to handle very biased input if possible.